# How long can a passenger aircraft glide without engine power?

Tags: engine-failure, glide-ratio

Assuming that the aircraft is cruising at 36000 ft and lost engine power, how long could a passenger aircraft glide?

Comment: I‘m sure that’s been answered elsewhere already, but until someone digs out a link for proof I‘d go with an ideal maximum value of 20ft forward for every feet altitude which is good enough for a rough estimate. Real scenarios where this happened (search machine keywords: Gimli glider and Air Transat Lajes) involved substantially shorter glides though.

Comment: The average airliner has about a 15:1 glide ratio.  If it is 1 mile high, it can glide about 15 miles.  36,000 ft is about 6 miles high so it should be able to glide about  90 miles. (6 x 15 = 90)